# Batch file that looks for changes in folder and uploads changes to ftp

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I'm looking to make a script that monitors a folder on the computer for any changes to be made. When those changes are made, the script should connect to the ftp and transfer those changes to the ftp account.

I'm trying to use WinSCP but I can't get it to work properly..

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftp://user:password@ftpaddress.com/
cd /Folder2
keepuptodate C:\Folder1 /Folder2
close
```

Comment: your code looks fine, do you get an error ?

Comment: I don't think I get an error. When I run the .bat, it closes right away. I'm not entirely sure how to debug it correctly.

Comment: the bat file has to be called like this: `WinSCP.com /script=PathOfYourBatFile`.

Comment: It is called like that. When I run it, it shuts off right away.

Comment: Please include an exact copy of the `.bat` file you use to run the WinSCP script.

Comment: @echo off
winscp.com /script=test.txt